# How do I separate my code into different lines in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I wish to declare a jQuery variable, but it's several lines long. How do I separate the codes  over a few lines? This is what I'm currently doing.

```
$("#elementid").html("<option value='1'>Some oranges</option>
<option value='2'>More Oranges</option>
<option value='3'>Even more oranges</option>");
```

Comment: Where is the HTML coming from? If it's dynamic you can create the DOM elements manually, which may be quicker.

Comment: I'm pretty new to jQuery, so I'm going to try hardcoding this in first :P

Answer (score 3):

Use string concatenation use plus operator `+`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jpNFr/1/)**

```
$("#elementid").html("<option value='1'>Some oranges</option>" +
"<option value='2'>More Oranges</option>" +
"<option value='3'>Even more oranges</option>");
```

or use `\` at end of line

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jpNFr/)**

```
$("#elementid").html("<option value='1'>Some oranges</option> \
<option value='2'>More Oranges</option> \
<option value='3'>Even more oranges</option>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate it:

```
$("#elementid").html("<option value='1'>Some oranges</option>" + 
    "<option value='2'>More Oranges</option>" + 
    "<option value='3'>Even more oranges</option>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use '+' sign:

```
$("#elementid").html("<option value='1'>Some oranges</option>"
    + "<option value='2'>More Oranges</option>"
    + "<option value='3'>Even more oranges</option>");
```

or use a different jQuery approach:

```
$("#elementid").append("<option value='1'>Some oranges</option>")
.append("<option value='2'>More Oranges</option>")
.append("<option value='3'>Even more oranges</option>");
```